# Use error outside catch block

Tags: php, try-catch

Let's work with an example like this:

```
try {
    if( $var == false ) {
        throw new Exception('Fail');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is there any way i can use `$error` outside the catch block?
If i try to print it outside,it shows nothing , so i'm sure i'm doing this wrong. Any help would be apreciated.

**EDIT:** This is my exact situation of the code [click](https://eval.in/615775)

I need to use $error , in another piece of code , outside of the class

Comment: first try removing return false

Comment: i already tried that,not working

Comment: You can just use it... https://repl.it/CiM2

Comment: @RyanVincent , sorry for replying so late , i updated your code with my exact situation , and is not working , maybe you can figure why,thank you https://eval.in/615775

Comment: Try looking at this one: https://eval.in/615876

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if no error happens. Else it will return the error.

```
$error = false;
try {
  if( $var == false ){
    throw new Exception('Fail');
  }
} catch (Exception $e){
  $error = $e->getMessage();      
}
return $error;
```

It depends on your implementation whether to return true or false.

Comment: a bit more detail would be appreciated. Add your code where you want to print the #error variable for instance. Or the complete function in which this try catch appears

Comment: https://eval.in/616087  Check this updated version of your code. You were not calling the function myFunc() at all. Plus you should be aware of the context of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are returning the error message, if you remove the return false statement, and try to print outside the loop it will print.

you can do that in 2 way:

Option1:

```
try {
  if( $var == false ){
    throw new Exception('Fail');
  }
} catch (Exception $e){
  $error = $e->getMessage();
//  return false;
}
```

print_r($error);

Option 2:

```
try {
  if( $var == false ){
    throw new Exception('Fail');
  }
} catch (Exception $e){
  return $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not
The $error is declard inside the catch.
You your function throws a Exception don't use try cactch. just throw the Exception

Your function should return just one type;
If it returns boolean, return aways boolean

Maybe if you need to print the error, print it inside the catch

Comment: You can (https://repl.it/CiM2). *"Your function should return just one type"*...That statement may be true for methods/functions, which this (doesn't look like) is in.

Comment: OK... you can, but It's out of the scope. you should not.